Jolt transformation - set boolean is true if value exist in second array
I have 2 arrays that I want to merge. The first array is a layered one, the second is a flat array. I want to use data from the second array as input for the first array.
This is an example of the input:
{
  "OrganisationUnitsSub": {
    "organisationUnits": [
      {
        "globalUnitId": "1323224",
        "childOrganizationUnits": [
          {
            "globalUnitId": "14243245",
            "childOrganizationUnits": [
              {
                "globalUnitId": "235215"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "OrganisationUnitsMain": {
    "organisationUnits": [
      {
        "globalUnitId": "1323224"
      }
    ]
  }
}

This is the jolt I tried so far:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "OrganisationUnitsSub": {
        "organisationUnits": {
          "*": {
            "globalUnitId": "Sub.units[&1].globalUnitId",
            "childOrganizationUnits": {
              "*": {
                "globalUnitId": "Sub.units[&3].childUnits[&1].globalUnitId",
                "childOrganizationUnits": {
                  "*": {
                    "globalUnitId": "Sub.units[&5].childUnits[&3].childUnits[&1].globalUnitId"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "OrganisationUnitsMain": {
        "organisationUnits": {
          "*": {
            "globalUnitId": "Main.units[&1].globalUnitId"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Sub": {
        "units": {
          "*": {
            "addedToMain": false,
            "childUnits": {
              "*": {
                "addedToMain": false,
                "childUnits": {
                  "*": {
                    "addedToMain": false
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Sub": {
        "units": {
          "*": {
            "addedToMain": "=if(=false, @(1,globalUnitId), @(2,Main.units[&1].globalUnitId), true, false)",
            "childUnits": {
              "*": {
                "addedToMain": "=if(=false, @(1,globalUnitId), @(3,Main.units[&3].globalUnitId), true, false)",
                "childUnits": {
                  "*": {
                    "addedToMain": "=if(=false, @(1,globalUnitId), @(4,Main.units[&5].globalUnitId), true, false)"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Sub": {
        "units": {
          "*": {
            "globalUnitId": "OrganisationUnitsSub.organisationUnits[&1].globalUnitId",
            "addedToMain": "OrganisationUnitsSub.organisationUnits[&1].addedToMain",
            "childUnits": {
              "*": {
                "globalUnitId": "OrganisationUnitsSub.organisationUnits[&3].childOrganizationUnits[&1].globalUnitId",
                "addedToMain": "OrganisationUnitsSub.organisationUnits[&3].childOrganizationUnits[&1].addedToMain",
                "childUnits": {
                  "*": {
                    "globalUnitId": "OrganisationUnitsSub.organisationUnits[&5].childOrganizationUnits[&3].childOrganizationUnits[&1].globalUnitId",
                    "addedToMain": "OrganisationUnitsSub.organisationUnits[&5].childOrganizationUnits[&3].childOrganizationUnits[&1].addedToMain"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


Eventually I want all entries in the first array to be checked on the second array based on the globalUnitId. If present in second array AddedToMain should be set to true else false
Expected outcome:
{
  "OrganisationUnitsSub" : {
    "organisationUnits" : [ {
      "globalUnitId" : "1323224",
      "addedToMain" : true,
      "childOrganizationUnits" : [ {
        "globalUnitId" : "14243245",
        "addedToMain" : false,
        "childOrganizationUnits" : [ {
          "globalUnitId" : "235215",
          "addedToMain" : false
        } ]
      } ]
    } ]
  }
}


Hi Nick. Due to addedToMain attribute of OrganisationUnitsSub.OrganisationUnits is missing in the childOrganizationUnits array, then you added "addedToMain" : "false", didnt you ?

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but default should be addedToMain: False. But if that globalUnitId is present in second array it should set it to True

Either I didn't understand your logic :) All the attributes of the upper array are kept and none of the attributes of the lower array remains in the desired result for the current case. What if some attributes of them missing for an of them ?

Upper is the main list of which we should always keep all the entries. From the second we should pick addedToMain based on the globalUnitId. And default should be false.

There's no addedToMain but addedToClic is, and its value is no true, the logc is yet not clear and doesn't cover all cases

I have simplified the question and also added the expected outcome. @BarbarosÖzhan

Assuming you have a finite number of layers(3 as in this case), we can apply the following transformation :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*ts*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "globalUnitId": "&(3,1)tsSub.&2[&1].&[]",
            "*ionUnits": {
              "*": {
                "globalUnitId": "&(5,1)tsSub.&4[&3].&2[&1].&[]",
                "*ionUnits": {
                  "*": {
                    "globalUnitId": "&(7,1)tsSub.&6[&5].&4[&3].&2[&1].&[]"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "addedToMain_temp1": "=size(@(1,globalUnitId))",
            "addedToMain_temp2": "=intSum(-1,@(1,addedToMain_temp1))",
            "addedToMain_temp3": "=intSum(-2,@(1,addedToMain_temp1))",
            "addedToMain_temp4": ["=divide(1,@(1,addedToMain_temp2))", false],
            "addedToMain_temp5": ["=divide(1,@(1,addedToMain_temp3))", true],
            "*ionUnits": {
              "*": {
                "addedToMain_temp1": "=size(@(1,globalUnitId))",
                "addedToMain_temp2": "=intSum(-1,@(1,addedToMain_temp1))",
                "addedToMain_temp3": "=intSum(-2,@(1,addedToMain_temp1))",
                "addedToMain_temp4": ["=divide(1,@(1,addedToMain_temp2))", false],
                "addedToMain_temp5": ["=divide(1,@(1,addedToMain_temp3))", true],
                "*ionUnits": {
                  "*": {
                    "addedToMain_temp1": "=size(@(1,globalUnitId))",
                    "addedToMain_temp2": "=intSum(-1,@(1,addedToMain_temp1))",
                    "addedToMain_temp3": "=intSum(-2,@(1,addedToMain_temp1))",
                    "addedToMain_temp4": ["=divide(1,@(1,addedToMain_temp2))", false],
                    "addedToMain_temp5": ["=divide(1,@(1,addedToMain_temp3))", true]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "addedToMain": ["=toBoolean(@(1,addedToMain_temp4))", "=toBoolean(@(1,addedToMain_temp5))"],
            "*ionUnits": {
              "*": {
                "addedToMain": ["=toBoolean(@(1,addedToMain_temp4))", "=toBoolean(@(1,addedToMain_temp5))"],
                "*ionUnits": {
                  "*": {
                    "addedToMain": ["=toBoolean(@(1,addedToMain_temp4))", "=toBoolean(@(1,addedToMain_temp5))"]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "ONE",
            "childOrganizationUnits": {
              "*": {
                "glob*": "ONE",
                "childOrganizationUnits": {
                  "*": {
                    "glob*": "ONE"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "addedToMain*": "",
            "childOrganizationUnits": {
              "*": {
                "addedToMain*": "",
                "childOrganizationUnits": {
                  "*": {
                    "addedToMain*": ""
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

where I've used the logic of division by zero after matching the related attributes for some of which having size of 2 vs. some of which with size of 1, will result true vs. false respectively.

But if we can have multiple entries on all the levels this might not work I guess?

Yes, right exactly @Nick

But is it doable? Also in the output the structure and fields slightly differ I think.

@Nick As I already presented, possible but unfortunately not in dynamic or generic sense.
